How to improve a join between two huge tables in snowflake
How to improve a join between two huge tables, one tables contains 4 billion records and another contains 2 billion records in snowflake on L size warehouse. These join occurs when thoughtspot triggers a query on snowflake. Currently it is taking 4 mins. I want to bring it down to less than 10 secs. I tried doing clustering, QAS etc. The join is inner join and relation ship is one to many.
I tried Query acceleration service, clustering, increased warehouse size.
Please find he below query
SELECT 
  DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', "ta_1"."DATE") "ca_1", 
  "ta_2"."FEATURELEVEL1" "ca_2", 
  count(DISTINCT "ta_3"."EVENTUUID") "ca_3"
FROM "C_GOLD"."PRODUCT_USAGE"."FEATURESBRIDGE" "MTA_0"
  JOIN "C_GOLD"."PRODUCT_USAGE"."MAPPEDFEATURES" "ta_2"
    ON "MTA_0"."FEATUREID" = "ta_2"."FEATUREID"
  JOIN "C_GOLD"."PRODUCT_USAGE"."PRODUCTEVENTS" "ta_3"
    ON (
      "MTA_0"."APPSTRINGID" = "ta_3"."APPSTRINGID"
      AND "MTA_0"."EVENTUUID" = "ta_3"."EVENTUUID"
      AND "MTA_0"."DATEKEY" = "ta_3"."DATEKEY"
    )
  JOIN "C_GOLD"."MASTER_DATA"."DATEDIM" "ta_1"
    ON "ta_3"."DATEKEY" = "ta_1"."DATEKEY"
  JOIN "C_GOLD"."MASTER_DATA"."COMPANIES" "ta_5"
    ON "ta_3"."COMPANYID" = "ta_5"."COMPANYID"
  JOIN "C_GOLD"."MASTER_DATA"."PRODUCTTAGS" "MTA_1"
    ON "ta_3"."PRODUCTTAGID" = "MTA_1"."PRODUCTTAGID"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "C_GOLD"."MASTER_DATA"."PARENTVIEW" "ta_4"
    ON "MTA_1"."PARENTTAGID" = "ta_4"."PARENTTAGID"
WHERE (
  "ta_1"."DATE" >= DATE('2023-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND "ta_1"."DATE" < DATE('2024-08-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
  AND LOWER("ta_4"."PRODUCTTAGNAME") = 'smart 3d'
  AND "ta_5"."ISINTERNAL" = FALSE
)
GROUP BY 
  "ca_1", 
  "ca_2"
ORDER BY "ca_1" ASC NULLS LAST
;

The Huge tables are Productevents and FeatureBridge.


HI can you please send us the table structure, the query which you are trying to improve the performance and the execution plan.

How many records do you expect in the resultset? If it is in the billions then I doubt you'd get it down to 10s query time

with and without clustering what was the performance. ?

@PIG, with clustering the join took 1.35 seconds, without clustering join took 1.40 seconds.

@HimanshuKandpal Provided the table structure and the query

@NickW the output is only between hundred to two hundred
